# Does WordPress trigger index.php when the page is cached?

Tags: php, wordpress, caching

All pages on my site are cached using the WP Rocket plugin, and everybody is telling me that the root **index.php** is not triggered when a page is cached.

I went ahead and added this piece of code to my root index.php to track its executions:

```
error_log( date('[ Y-m-d H:i:s ] ', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] ) . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ."\n", 3, dirname( __FILE__ ) . "/index.php.log" );
```

I checked the log and indeed the index.php seems to not trigger on cached pages.

What I don't understand is that online guides about WordPress loading sequence say that index.php is the very first thing that gets executed when you visit a site. It loads wp-blog-header.php, then wp-load.php sets up the WordPress environment, etc.

https://medium.com/@dendeffe/wordpress-loading-sequence-a-guided-tour-e077c7dbd119
https://www.mikeinmonospace.com/wordpress-internals-loading-sequence/

So what am I missing? Why isn't index.php triggered when the page is cached? Is there anything triggered **before** index.php that loads the cached page?

Comment: Check what the .htaccess file on the project root level contains. The plugin is probably circumventing the internal rewrite to the index.php on that level already.

Comment: Thanks, CBroe, this is very helpful! I was thinking of exactly the same, but since I'm not a professional developer, I couldn't properly examine the contents of the .htaccess file. But, yeah, that makes perfect sense. There are bunch of Rewrite Rules and Conditions in that file added by WP Rocket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WordPress (and most modern CMS's, in fact) the [Front Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) pattern is used which routes all requests for the CMS to a single file, which is often `index.php`. However, as @CBroe said, this is **not** the CMS that is doing that, it is a rule in the web server. For an Apache-based web server this is in the `.htaccess` file, for IIS it might be a `web.config` file and for Nginx it could be in one of the server directives.

When a caching solution is used, they usually *also* inject rules into the web server, but *before* the CMS's rules, which means that `index.php` is no longer the first and therefore default rule.